# How to replace `0`s with missing values according to a series of numbers in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, series

I have a `numpy` array with a series of `ints`. I want to fill up the `0`s with the missing values in the series.

Originally, I have these values in a column of a `pandas` dataframe, but for simplicity, I decided to post the question using a `numpy` array instead.

```
>>> a = np.array([15, 25, 0, 45, 0, 0, 75, 85])
>>> a
>>> array([15, 25,  0, 45,  0,  0, 75, 85])
```

I want the output as,

```
>>> array([15, 25,  35, 45,  55,  65, 75, 85])
```

---

I want to solve this problem without using loops as that would defeat the purpose of using `numpy` or `pandas` and the code would be much slower using loops.

I would not want to replace the entire column with new values which would as a side effect update the `0`s as well.

I only want to update the `0`s with the missing values according to the series.

Comment: Where do you get the missing values from? Or do you assume you have an arithmetic sequence?

Comment: Do you want to replace the zeros with the mean of the previous and following value? Otherwise I'm not sure, whether I understand how you want to fill them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straight forward with pandas. You can apply a linear interpolation using [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) (its default interpolation method is `linear`):

```
a = np.array([15, 25, 0, 45, 0, 0, 75, 85])
s = pd.Series(a)
s.mask(s.eq(0)).interpolate()

0    15.0
1    25.0
2    35.0
3    45.0
4    55.0
5    65.0
6    75.0
7    85.0
dtype: float64
```